# Insert checked list box to database

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, checkedlistbox

I have 6 checked boxes with more than 10 values each in my Visual Basic project using Visual Studio.
I would like to insert the values of the checked box into one table, all values of checked box into one cell (if possible).

For example, I have table called Food that has user id, Fruits, Vegetables, and Snacks.
Assuming that I have 3 checked boxes as well, I want to have all Fruits checked in Fruit column as it represents one person.

I started my code like this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Food (id, Fruits, Vegetables, Snacks) VALUES ('" & txtIDR.Text & "','" & CheckedFruits.CheckedItems.ToString & "','" & CheckedVegetables.CheckedItems.ToString & "','" & CheckedSnacks.CheckedItems.ToString & "','" & ")"
```

I didn't got an error messages but I'm afraid that I did something wrong with the way I handled the checked list box.

Please advise.

Comment: A good place to start would be to debug the code, and copy the value of 'sql' and see if it looks like a valid SQL query.

Comment: Use an numeric for the values in your table and create bit attribute (from these values: 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,etc), based on the checked items. Example of you have 5 check boxes and the user only selected entries 1, 3 and 5, then your value will be 21.

Comment: Also please consider using sql parameters to make you query robust against type mismatches and avoid sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry didn't see it was `CheckListBox`

to access a property of the CheckListBox you should use:

```
CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Item(0)
```

**Where 0 is your item index**

However you need to remember that `CheckedItems.Item` will only exist if something is checked if you try to call `CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Item(0)` but nothing is checked you will get Index out of bounds

An easy way to get all checked values easily is with a `For Each`:

```
For Each check In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
    Debug.WriteLine(check)
Next
```

You could have something like this:

```
Public Function CreateSQL() As SqlCommand
    Dim Fruits As String = ""
    Dim Vegetables As String = ""
    Dim Snacks As String = ""
    For Each check In CheckedFruits.CheckedItems
        Fruits = Fruits & check & ","
    Next
    If Fruits.LastIndexOf(",") = Fruits.Length - 1 Then
        Fruits = Fruits.Remove(Fruits.LastIndexOf(","), 1)
    End If
    For Each check In CheckedVegetables.CheckedItems
        Vegetables = Vegetables & check & ","
    Next
    If Vegetables.LastIndexOf(",") = Vegetables.Length - 1 Then
        Vegetables = Vegetables.Remove(Vegetables.LastIndexOf(","), 1)
    End If
    For Each check In CheckedSnacks.CheckedItems
        Snacks = Snacks & check & ","
    Next
    If Snacks.LastIndexOf(",") = Snacks.Length - 1 Then
        Snacks = Snacks.Remove(Snacks.LastIndexOf(","), 1)
    End If
    MyCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Food (id, Fruits, Vegetables, Snacks) VALUES (@UserID, @Fruits, @Vegetables, @Snacks)", dbConn)
    MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", TicBoxText.Text)
    MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fruits", Fruits)
    MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vegetables", Vegetables)
    MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Snacks", Snacks)
    Return MyCommand
End Sub
```

[CheckedListBox MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.aspx)

Comment: So do I have to do it before my sql statement? and for all checked boxed I have? I didn't get how to use it in my question.

Comment: @FNM Before your SQL statement you need to go through all checkvegeables and add them to a string and do the same to snacks and friuts and then execute the query

Comment: Could you show me please how to do the sql command using my same method? Will it be the same? ( just to add the first statements).

Comment: @FNM could you take the time to read my answer before comenting since I have already given you all the code

Comment: What I did is For Each -- Next, Then in my code replaced CheckedFruits.CheckedItems.ToString by Fruits. Is it correct?

Comment: I did read it but I got confused a little bit by your way in writing the sql statement.

Comment: What do you find confusing? All you have to do is copy paste my code instead of your sql line. Please check: [How to write SQL Insert](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) and also: [How to use SQL Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)